# Как в $.post передать неизвестное количество data?

Tags: jquery

```
var data = {
$(this).attr('name') : $(this).val()
}
$.post('link.php', data, function(){})
```

Я хочу отдать на съедение $.post неизвестное количество параметров(data). Как такое реализовать ?
Киньте пожалуйста какой нибудь пример как такое реализовать
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте про функции [.serialize()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) и [.serializeArray()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)
Возможно, что это решит пробоему. Если нет, то вам надо самому загнать все значения в массив, который и отправить обработчику.

Comment: .serializeArray() эта функция работает как надо. Спасибо